# How do I get the old values partitoned for each group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
ID | Type | Val0 | Creation_date
1  |  A   |  V1  | 24sep, 2011
2  |  B   |  X1  | 15 dec, 2001
3  |  A   |  V1  | 27oct, 2008
4  |  A   |  V2  | 19oct, 2003
5  |  B   |  X2  | 15 dec, 2000
6  |  C   |  X3  | 23Dec, 2001
7  |  B   |  X2  | 15 dec, 1990
```

I want to keep only the latest values for a particular type and extract out values which are old. So, for above table, I want these items to be extracted out - V2, X2 which i can delete later.

since A is having the latest value as V1, B is having the latest value as X1 and C is having the latest value as X3.

Can anybody suggest me how i can do this using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the values, you can use `keep`:

```
select type,
       max(val0) keep (dense_rank first order by creation_date asc) as latest_val0
from t
group by type;
```

If you want the entire row, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by creation_date asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @Neha . . . If you want the oldest values, just use `asc` instead of `desc`.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, Type, Val, Creation_date ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 'V1', DATE '2011-09-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 'X1', DATE '2001-12-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', 'V1', DATE '2008-10-27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A', 'V2', DATE '2003-10-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'B', 'X2', DATE '2000-12-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'C', 'X3', DATE '2001-12-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'B', 'X2', DATE '1990-12-15' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ID,
       TYPE,
       val,
       Creation_date
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LAST_VALUE( val ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY type
             ORDER BY creation_date
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
          ) AS last_val
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE val <> last_val;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID TYPE VAL CREATION_DATE     
---------- ---- --- -------------------
         4 A    V2  2003-10-19 00:00:00 
         7 B    X2  1990-12-15 00:00:00 
         5 B    X2  2000-12-15 00:00:00
```